# Eliminar filas de un JTable Java

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` llamado `tabla_clientes` del cual quiero **eliminar las filas seleccionadas.**

Mi problema está en que no se activa `button_eliminar` cuando selecciono 1 o más filas del `JTable`, y se desactiva cuando se hayan conseguido eliminar correctamente o cuando se deseleccionen todas.

Inicialmente `button_eliminar` está deshabilitado al no tener ninguna fila seleccionada.

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema y cómo sé que fila he seleccionado para ser eliminada con mi función eliminar_cliente?**

**Código:**

```
public class Listado_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    public Listado_clientes() {
        initComponents();

        //Inicialmente el button_eliminar está deshabilitado.
        button_eliminar.setEnabled(false);

        //Si seleccionamos 1 o más filas, activamos el button.
        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila >= 0){
            button_eliminar.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            button_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
        }

        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

            //Hacer NO editable la tabla.
            tabla_clientes.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

            //Copiamos la tabla...
            ...
    }

    private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();

        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila >= 0) {
           int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
           for (int i=0; i<filasselec.length; i++){
                modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
           }
        }
        button_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**Código eliminar_cliente():**

```
public static void eliminar_cliente(String DNI){
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String eliminar_clientes = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE dni = '"+DNI+"';";
            int resultado1 = 1;
            //System.out.println(eliminar_clientes);
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate(eliminar_clientes);
            if(resultado1<=0){
                throw new SQLException();
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Cliente eliminado de la tabla clientes.");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Conexiones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parece que el código donde decides si el botón tiene que estar activado/desactivado (comentario //Si seleccionamos 1 o más filas, activamos el button.) lo tienes en el constructor, por lo que se ejecutará una vez nada más cuando se cree el objeto. ¿No debería ejecutarse cada vez que cambie la fila/filas seleccionadas?

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA Así es, ¿el elemento JTable tiene un action para comprobar los valores de las filas seleccionadas? El más cercano que veo es el KeyPressed